# MVC Background work and incremental rendering

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

Sorry, but I am still quite a noob when it comes to MVC and i've reached the limit of my knowledge for this scenario.

The example below is an "abstract" of my request as the specifics of my implementation is quite complicated.

The model below contains a record of how many hours a particular person worked on a specific project for a given period.

```
public class WorkDone
{
    public string Team {get; set;}
    public string Employee {get; set;}
    public string Period {get; set;}
    public string Project {get; set;}
    public int HoursWorked {get; set;}
```

}

Now, the in my form, the requester can selected a date range, and then chose one or more teams... But the calculation engine takes 5 to 10 seconds to process an employee's time records.

**Approach 1**

Synchronous approach, I would simple AJAX post the request to the controller, collate the data and then return in a partial view however, as the calculations to obtain the HoursWorked is a long and complex one, the form takes a long time to load.

**Approach 2**

Post the request as above, but in the controller, execute the calculations in a multi-threaded approach using Background worker threads. The risk here is IIS recycling all work is lost, even if some work has actually been completed.

**ideal world**

What I would like to happen is the request is Posted and then as results become available, then they get displayed... A bit like those comparison sites where new quotes from different companies pop in as their respective APIs complete.

So, I know its going to involve async processing but but I am at a loss as to what question to ask Stackexchange / goolge to get the right answer...

**Note to stackexchange mods**

I know this is not an explicit "I have this problem" and more of a "how do i do this"... But I am note sure where on SE you can ask these sorts of questions so please point me in the right direction and dont just close it as "not a real question"...

Comment: I did something similar and involved having the client poll the server for completion status. It was a very chatty process. I wish there was something out of the box. The closet I can think would be signal R, however, like polling a controller method from the clients, it is a lot of effort to replace an hourglass.

Comment: If you're open for suggestions then I would recommend the following. Post the form to server. Then the server either initiates the work in a separate service (such as a windows service), or by doing a fire-and-forget to a WCF-service. Then, when the work is complete, let the client know by pushing it to the client with SignalR.

Comment: If you query is taking that long, it suggest some problems with you database design

Comment: @StephenMuecke ...its not a database design, its a legacy system that we have to access and it has a lot of latency